# Default View Fails to Load when navigating from UIImageView in Montouch

Tags: iphone, uinavigationcontroller, uiimageview, xamarin.ios

I'm really stuck, I can't seem to navigate correctly to a new UIViewController from a tap gesture when tapping on a UIImageView.  I'm using MonoTouch storyboards.  If I create a button on my first view controller, and control drag it onto my second view controller using push, the navigation works correctly and all the controls on my second view controller are all instantiated.  When I use the code below in the tap gesture handler, it navigates to the second view controller, but all my controls are null, and if I don't try and access any of them the screen is just black.

I've had to overload the constructor for my second view controller to be able to instantiate it with no values, which I think might be the issue, but I don't know what to pass in to the original constructor as all the examples I can find are navigating from table navigators etc.

here is the code in view controller one:

```
[Export("HandleImageTap")]
public void HandleImageTap(UITapGestureRecognizer recogniser)
{
    ViewControllerTwo myViewController2 = new ViewControllerTwo();
    myViewController2.SelectedID = 2;
    NavigationController.PushViewController(myViewController2, true);
}
```

Here is the constructor in the the second view controller:

```
public partial class ViewControllerTwo : UIViewController
{
    public int SelectedID { get; set; }

    public ViewControllerTwo (IntPtr handle) : base (handle)
    {

    }

    public ViewControllerTwo () : base (NSObjectFlag.Empty)
    {

    }
```

If someone could please help I would be eternally grateful as I'm really stuck and have been for about 1/2 a day!

Thanks a lot,

Davoc

Edit: Added the : base (NSObjectFlag.Empty) to the second constructor as this hasn't changed the behaviour.

Answer (score 0):

Your default constructor for ViewControllerTwo() is not chaining up correctly, try using:

```
public ViewControllerTwo () : base (NSObjectFlag.Empty)
```

Additionally, you might want to look at UIStoryboardSegue

Comment: Hi Miguel,Thanks for your response, I've just tried that and it's still performing in the same way as before, so for instance if I try to access a label on the second view controller the label is null, which isn't the case when I use a button on the first view controller and control drag it to the second, using push.  Is the method I'm using the correct on for moving between view controllers programatically?  Thanks,

Comment: I've noticed that I can create a view at runtime and add it into this.View.Subviews and it will display, it's just the view I have created through the storyboard designer which doesn't display and is null using the methods above.  Is there something I need to be doing to make sure that the designer created views are instantiated when I instantiate the view controller?  Thanks

Comment: Hard to tell from your snippets above.   I would need to look at a self-contained test case.

Comment: I decided to just create a view class made up of the controls in the positions I needed them and then added that into the subviews for the view controller.  I have a feeling it might be a defect as I spent a long time looking into it and couldn't work out how to get it to initialise correctly.  The above code snippets are all you need to navigate between 2 view controllers when one is a UINavigationController, so you should be able to see if you get the same behaviour as I do if you want.